# Adding/deleting weighted edges to a weighted graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

**How can I add and delete weighted edges in a weighted graph?**

Using `Graph` in *Mathematica* I want to add a weighted edge to a weighted graph. The problem is `EdgeAdd` seems to always return an unweighted graph. For example:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, EdgeWeight -> {5, 11}]
g1 = EdgeDelete[g, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3]
g2 = EdgeAdd[g, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3]
```

Here, `g1` has its edge weights messed up, so `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` does not work. It seems the list of edge weights is too long since no element has been deleted. `g2`, on the other hand, is an unweighted graph. I even tried wrapping the added edge in

```
Property[1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, EdgeWeight -> 13]
```

but that only got me an error when supplied to `EdgeAdd`.

I can bypass the `EdgeDelete` thing quite easily by afterwards readjusting the `EdgeWeights` list, but I haven't found a way to solve the `EdgeAdd` problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `EdgeDelete[G, e]` does not remove the appropriate weight $w_e$ from the properties of graph $G$ (I would say this is a bug, though it is the last one in a very long list for `Graph`...). First, set up explicit edge and weight lists, and a one-to-one mapping for conversions:

```
e = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3};
w = {5, 11};
r = Thread[e -> w];

g = Graph[e, EdgeWeight -> w, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];
{PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight], MatrixForm@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@g, g}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g1 = EdgeDelete[g, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3];
{PropertyValue[g1, EdgeWeight], MatrixForm@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@g1, g1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is clearly reported by `PropertyValue` that `g1` still keeps unnecessary weights.

Now one can rely on `SetProperty`, though it requires possibly tedious tracking and re-setting of weights:

```
g2 = SetProperty[EdgeDelete[g, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3], 
              EdgeWeight -> (DeleteCases[e, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3] /. r)];
{PropertyValue[g2, EdgeWeight], MatrixForm@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@g2, g2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same method works for `EdgeAdd`:

```
g3 = SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3], 
              EdgeWeight -> Append[PropertyValue[g2, EdgeWeight], 4]];
{PropertyValue[g3, EdgeWeight], MatrixForm@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@g3, g3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The weighted edge that I add seems to be placed in the wrong place. E.g. I've a weighted random graph g, EdgeList[g]={1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6} and random weights w={0.38629, 0.967065, 0.281823, 0.689528, 0.0222693, 0.604908, 0.875763}. Then I add an edge: g3 = SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g, {6 <-> 3}], 
  EdgeWeight -> Append[PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight], 4.]]. The result is the edge with weight 4 is added between vertices 2 and 3 (instead of verteces 3 and 6).